# If $m>n$ prove $m \,\,\mathrm{mod}\,\, n <\frac m2$

Tags: number-theory

I am starting to study some number theory and in my book it has the question

If $m>n$ prove $m \,\,\mathrm{mod}\,\, n <\frac m2$

I have been trying this problem and have looked at some hints in the book, but can't take it much farther from here:

> If $n \leq  \frac m2$, then the claim follows since: $r = m \,\,\mathrm{mod}\,\, n < n$
>
> If $n > \frac m2$, then $r = m \,\,\mathrm{mod}\,\, n = m - n < \frac m2$

If someone could provide me some hints and point me in the direction this would be very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Looks like you've already proved it!  What exactly do you think you still need?

Comment: Do you not understand the proof as it is written?

Comment: Yes sorry I should have clarified, I wanted some insights on the hints and why it is approachedl ike that

Comment: We examin all the possible cases

Comment: @bill look now it is clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two cases:

$n\leq \frac{m}{2}$

so $m$ mod $n <n\leq \frac{m}{2}$

if $n>\frac{m}{2}$

let $m=kn+r$ with $k\in \mathbb N $ and $0\leq r <n$

so we have

$r= m$ mod $n$,

$m>n \implies k\geq 1$

$n>\frac{m}{2} \implies m<2n $

$\implies k<2 \implies k=1$

thus

$m=n+r$ and

$r=m-n<m-\frac{m}{2}$.

Comment: Why did you get the line k < 2

Comment: @bill if $kgeq 2$ it means $ m\geq 2n$ but $n>m/2$

Comment: @bill is it Ok now?